# Prepay mortgage

Tags: mortgage, real-estate

Let's say I want to prepay my entire mortgage and I have 22 years left in my 25 years mortgage.

In this case the bank imposes a penalty which is the **yearly interest for three months**. My question is, will this penalty apply on the entire 300,000$ mortgage let's say or the 60,000$ I would have paid in this 5 years cycle?

To put it in other words, the bank says that I need to do `prepaid_amount * yearly_interest / 4`. So the `prepaid amount` is the 60,000$ or the 300,000$?

P.S. The `division by 4` comes from the fact that I'm penalized with the `yearly_interest` for three months.

Comment: I chose not to pay-off a mortgage; Essentially I am getting money at 4 % ( the mort. rate) which I used in the stock market. Hopefully I keep making more than a 4 % stock return  and got to deduct mortgage interest ( until this year ). from income tax.  The money you don't pay on the mortgage could also used to buy a car and avoid a high rate car loan.

Comment: What do you mean by "this 5 years cycle" and just curious, but which country are you in?

Comment: This is entirely dependent on your mortgage conditions.